# HTML content injected into page via button click, THEN run jQuery to manipulate that content

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-injection, timing

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="yzms-filters-content">
  <div class="yzms-filter-item" data-form="99" data-id="youzify_members_search[xprofile][23][value][]"><span class="youzify-filter-value">Singles</span><i class="fas fa-times youzify-delete-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="yzms-filter-item" data-form="99" data-id="youzify_members_search[xprofile][18][value][]"><span class="youzify-filter-value">Recreation</span><i class="fas fa-times youzify-delete-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="yzms-filter-item" data-form="99" data-id="youzify_members_search[xprofile][86][value]"><span class="youzify-filter-value">Beginner</span><i class="fas fa-times youzify-delete-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="yzms-filter-item" data-form="99" data-id="youzify_members_search[xprofile][90][value]"><span class="youzify-filter-value">Beginner</span><i class="fas fa-times youzify-delete-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="yzms-filter-item" data-form="99" data-id="youzify_members_search[xprofile][94][value]"><span class="youzify-filter-value">Beginner</span><i class="fas fa-times youzify-delete-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="yzms-filter-item" data-form="99" data-id="youzify_members_search[xprofile][4][value]"><span class="youzify-filter-value">Male</span><i class="fas fa-times youzify-delete-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="yzms-filter-item" data-form="99" data-id="youzify_members_search[xprofile][15][value]"><span class="youzify-filter-value">Right-Handed</span><i class="fas fa-times youzify-delete-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="yzms-filter-item" data-form="99" data-id="youzify_members_search[xprofile][7][value]"><span class="youzify-filter-value">Las Vegas</span><i class="fas fa-times youzify-delete-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="yzms-filter-item" data-form="99" data-id="youzify_members_search[xprofile][10][value][]"><span class="youzify-filter-value">United States</span><i class="fas fa-times youzify-delete-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
const fieldLabel = {
 "4": "Gender",
 "7": "City",
 "10": "Country",
 "15": "R/L",
 "18": "Player Type",
 "23": "Prefers",
 "86": "Singles",
 "90": "Doubles",
 "94": "Mixed Doubles"
};

$(".yzms-filters-content .yzms-filter-item").each(function(index, element) {
        let dataIDs = $(element).attr("data-id");
        let fieldIDraw = dataIDs.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
        let fieldID = fieldIDraw[1].replace(/\[|\]/g,"");
        $(element).children("span").prepend(fieldLabel[fieldID], ": ");
});
```

When the page loads, the parent div, `<div class="yzms-filters-content">` is empty.  When a button is clicked, the child elements are injected.

The JavaScript above, edits the injected elements.  This code "works" (https://jsfiddle.net/quint/bvLheymk/105/).

However, there is a timing issue.  How can the script be run after the elements have been injected?

I don't have control over the code that performs the injection.

Comment: Put the JS logic which updates the DOM in a function, and call that function in the button's `click` which adds the content. If you don't have access to the existing button click handler, add a new one and call the function on a slight delay (assuming the content isn't loaded via AJAX). Alternatively, use a MutationObserver to determine when the DOM is updated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for the suggestions.  I did use their existing button to execute the script above, but it looks like it runs before the child elements are injected.  No bueno.  I don't know anything about a MutationObserver.  How could that be used?  I'll start research on that topic next...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, the MutationOberver was the ticket.  Thank you!!!